# React Native button animation not working when onPress action is called

Tags: react-native, react-redux, native-base

I have a button who's animation works as it should until I add an onPress event. Once the onPress is added, there is no feedback when I press the button.

I am using NativeBase for the button (although I don't think this should matter) and redux for the action to occur.

```
<Button block primary onPress={() => this.props.onChangeDetails({id: this.props.report.report.details.id, inspection: true})}>
  <Text style={nbStyles.buttonText}>Add Inspection Report</Text>
</Button>

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onChangeDetails: payload => {
      dispatch(editDetails(payload))
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why I'm not seeing any animation?

Comment: does your onChangeDetails function fire? And is your first parameter this.props.report.report or is that a typo?

Comment: @basudz yes, it does fire. if i comment out the dispatch the action works as expected. that param is correct.

Comment: @MollyHarper were you able to find any solution for this?